# Can you use multiple ad SDKs with SKAdNetwork?

Tags: skadnetwork

I am using Facebook ads, Google ads, and an MMP for other networks. I just need to track installs as conversions. I do not serve ads in the app.

My MMP is saying that you cannot have multiple SDKs sending info to SKAdNetwork because it will post back inaccurate information. I have not read this anywhere else.

It says you should only have one SDK posting conversions to SKAdNetwork.

[Screenshot of MMP's Blog post saying this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yG4C2.png)

My question is do I need to remove or disable Facebook and Google's registration to SKAdNetwork within my app so they don't post conversions to SKAdNetwork?

OR

Is it ok that all 3 SDKs post to SKAdNetwork?

Comment: having the exact same problem. @DVE did you find out anything in the meantime? Thanks a lot for any hint!

Comment: Not sure still... I tried both taking them out and also keeping them all in, I even switched MMPS. You should be able to keep all of them in from what I've been told so I just went with that. Either way all my install campaigns have tanked to a fraction of what they once were before SKAD and my data doesn't line up on any platform with any other platform :( So I'm probably not the best person to ask.

Comment: @dcts it's been some months since then, but did you get the answer? Multiple SDK is possible to use SKAdNetwork?

Comment: @ThomasRamé sorry unfortunately I did not. Please answer this question once you find out :)

Comment: You should put the link to the blog post instead of a screenshot that has no context.

Answer (score 0):

You technically only need to send one conversion value update and there will be some side effects if you send more than one (though if you handle all your app specific use cases then this might not matter).

Apple will send SKAN CVs to each of the networks you are using for optimization purposes so you shouldn't need to worry about that. I'd personally recommend that you streamline your own app flow to handle SKAN postbacks directly to Apple once.

SKAN 4.0 might make it more difficult if you send multiple CVs from different parties. The new features around multiple postbacks can now get sent to the ad networks based on cohort date and this could affect the optimizations that each of the ad networks use.